# What is WebIDL and (why) is it important?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

The WebIDL spec is in last call and [the buzz](http://infrequently.org/2011/10/real-constructors-webidl-last-call/) is that this is a big step for the web. However, I can't find much useful information on it and why it is important.

I understand it defines an interface but an interface for what? How does WebIDL relate to ECMAscript, JavaScript, HTML or the DOM? Will this affect the life of the humble web developer or is it for a different crowd - browser developers perhaps?

Links to articles are welcome.

Answer (score 7):

I would say that it relates to the DOM and ways to manipulate it through languages other than JavaScript. JavaScript already has ways to manipulate the DOM, but that's not a standard, and WebIDL is probably an interface for other languages.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose then, that could mean that in the future that there may be many more `****Script`s - C#Script, RubyScript, FortranScript, etc. Is that what you mean?

Comment: i'm not sure what's the direction, but i think they want to make an standarized API for DOM.

Comment: It relates to DOM just as much as JavaScript relates to DOM. Meaning not much at all.

Answer (score 7):

One area where WebIDL is important is typed language compilers targeting JavaScript. I work on a tool called WebSharper that compiles F# to JavaScript; a much better known example is GWT for Java. In these frameworks our users want typed access to available functionality, with code completion and checking. We used to describe F#-JS mappings by hand or in semi-formal semi-automated ways. It sounds like compiling WebIDL will help a whole lot to be more up-to-date with the evolving HTML5 spec. Ideally we could even convince JavaScript library writers to provide or generate WebIDL for their code.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one. The usefulness of WebIDL lies in it being able to function as an interface between a program and its runtime library platform.